# How to inject a dependency into Command Pattern in Python without DI lib?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I'm new to Python and I would like to keep things simple for now. Here's what I'm trying to solve. I have implemented a Command Pattern application in Python. One thing, I'm not sure is how to "inject" a `Repository` class. So it can be used for all of the sub classes. Here's the code.

```
command.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from report.repository.database import Database


class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.repository = Database() ## how do I inject this instead of init it here.


    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass
```

```
database.py
class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.drivers = {}
    
    def add_driver(self, name):
        self.drivers[name] = {}
```

```
add_driver.py
from report.parser.command import Command


class AddDriver(Command):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name


    def execute(self):
        self.repository.add_driver(self.name)
```

Because I would like to be able to use the instance of `Database` later in the code to generate a report for the `drivers`. Coming from Java world, I could inject the instance of `database` using Guice. I'm not sure what's the best way to do that in Python.

I was thinking of just injecting in the `execute` method, but I would have other command that wouldn't need the `Database` which I think it will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an instance in database.py

```
# database.py
class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.drivers = {}
    
    def add_driver(self, name):
        self.drivers[name] = {}
db = Database()
```

then import it where ever needed.

```
# command.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from report.repository.database import db


class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.repository = db


    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass
```